# jest calls afterEach (teardown) before test finish only in debug mode

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I am using nodejs, nestjs, supertest, mongodb, mongoose.
My tests run is completed successfully, using command
npm run test:e2e from default nestjs package.json config.
When I execute my separate test in debug mode, from vscode debug view it fails with error of disposed mongodb connection. The test has  mutliple async requests calls which I await it returns after request is called and starts executing jest teardown afterEach and afterAll which is kinda strange for me.

My launch.json

```json
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest Current File e2e tests",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "args": [
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "--config",
        "${workspaceFolder}/test/jest-e2e.json"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest"
      }
    }
```

jest-e2e.json

```json
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

app.e2e-spec.ts

```typescript
describe('app (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let connection: Connection;
  let dbInitializer: DbInitializer;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await createAndCompileTestingModule();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

    await configApp(app);

    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
    const logger = new MyLogger(configService);
    connection = app.get(CustomConnectionService).getConnection();
    dbInitializer = new DbInitializer(connection, logger);
    await dbInitializer.seedDb();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await connection.db.dropCollection(dbInitializer.articleCollectionName);
    await connection.db.dropCollection(dbInitializer.userCollectionName);
  });

  it('/ (POST) creates article', async function () {
    expect.assertions(9);
    const userToLogin = {
      username: 'leane1Gra',
      password: 'cft0id32',
    };

    const httpServer = app.getHttpServer();

    const responseLogin = await request(httpServer)
      .post(`/${LoginEndPoint}`)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .send(userToLogin);

    expect(responseLogin.statusCode).toBe(201);

    const userLoginResponse = responseLogin.body as UserLoginResponse;

    const resposeGetUser = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get(`/${UsersEndpoint}/by-username`)
      .query({ username: userToLogin.username });

    expect(resposeGetUser.statusCode).toBe(200);

    const userFindByUsernameResponse =
      resposeGetUser.body as MappedUserResponse;

    const articleToCreate = {
      title: 'article a',
      subtitle: 'subtitle a',
      description: 'description a',
      category: 'history',
      ownerId: userFindByUsernameResponse.id,
    };

    const response = await request(httpServer)
      .post(`/${ArticlesEndpoint}`)
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userLoginResponse.user_jwt}`)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .send(articleToCreate);

    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
    expect(response.headers['content-type']).toMatch(/json/);

    const { updatedUser, newArticle } = response.body as CreateArticleResponse;

    expect(newArticle.id).toBeTruthy();
    expect(newArticle.title).toBe(articleToCreate.title);

    expect(updatedUser.id).toBeTruthy();
    expect(updatedUser.articleIds).toContain(newArticle.id);
    expect(updatedUser.numberOfArticles).toBe(
      userFindByUsernameResponse.numberOfArticles + 1,
    );
  });

}
```

I am adding a video of test run in debug mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the timeout after your it test. The max value for timeout is 32 bit signed integer.
You can debug your test during specified timeout without jest teardown called.

```typescript
it('/ (POST) creates article', async function () {
// test body omitted
},147483647)
```